# Im having trouble with a vectors question

Tags: vectors

Im not sure how the rules relating to this are but since the problematic question builds up on a paper with diagrams, i would like to show an image of the question.

image of the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3M6Y.jpg

I would really appreciate some help, thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Could you put questions directly here?

Comment: im sorry but i dont know how to, they include diagrams...